# Parameters, Logic Path not visible at run time in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Just after some ideas for why my parameters, logic path etc are suddenly not visible at run time? I've checked that the visible toggle in on "yes" so it's not that. Just wondering if anyone has any ideas what I might have done to cause this. Can see paths, plots, etc, but not process modelling blocks, functions, variables, parameters, events, so on

Comment: Would be good if you share some more details, especially (obviously) some screenshots. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow for asking good questions :)

Comment: Are you actually panning the canvas at runtime to see things outside the frame (blue square in the design canvas which determines the initial 'window size/position')?